# CSS parallax effect getting a vertical scrollbar and mis-behaving

Tags: html, css, parallax

I need a parallax effect in my website. I created this parallax by following [this](https://codepen.io/tribex/pen/mWNWdz) tutorial. It behaves perfect in tutorial and in my case as you can see, it's generating a vertical scrollbar and misbehaving.

> It scroll the inner scrollbar and keep the body as it is. When I
>   remove `overflow-y: auto;` from `#section-1.sec_wrapper`, the parallax
>   is not working. How can I make it work?

```css
#section-1.sec_wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}

#section-1.sec_wrapper .top-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#section-1.sec_wrapper .top-content:after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.parallax::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#section-2 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <!-- section 1 -->
  <section id="section-1" class="sec_wrapper">
    <div class="top-content parallax">
      <div class="welcome-txt">
        <p style="text-align: center;">hello! how are you?<br>we are</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section-2" class="sec_wrapper">

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I change the #section-1.sec_wrapper overflow property and the scroll has been gone but not sure about the animation. https://codepen.io/pixel-lab/pen/oPqNLx

Comment: @pixellab Thank you for your time sir. When `overflow` is hidden the parralax is gone. It's the default behavior appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please this now, I missed the example last time.
https://codepen.io/pixel-lab/pen/oPqNLx
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /* The height needs to be set to a fixed value for the effect to work.
   * 100vh is the full height of the viewport. */
  height: 100vh;
  /* The scaling of the images would add a horizontal scrollbar, so disable x overflow. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Enable scrolling on the page. */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Set the perspective to 2px. This is essentailly the simulated distance from the viewport to transformed objects.*/
  perspective: 2px;
}




/*
#section-1.sec_wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}*/

#section-1.sec_wrapper .top-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#section-1.sec_wrapper .top-content:after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.parallax::after {
  /* Display and position the pseudo-element */
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Move the pseudo-element back away from the camera,
   * then scale it back up to fill the viewport.
   * Because the pseudo-element is further away, it appears to move more slowly, like in real life. */
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  /* Force the background image to fill the whole element. */
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Keep the image from overlapping sibling elements. */
  z-index: -1;
}

#section-2 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- section 1 -->
  <section id="section-1" class="sec_wrapper parallax">
    <div class="top-content parallax">
      <div class="welcome-txt">
        <p style="text-align: center;">hello! how are you?<br>we are</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section-2" class="sec_wrapper ">

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far. I can't understand the code. You commented some of my css classes and added your's. You added some classes and wrote css , but I am unable to see them in the html. `.section` is in the css, but couldn't find in html.Can you elaborate the answer

Comment: I haven't used my own class, its form your example structure. I just maintain the structure form the given HTML, CSS...https://codepen.io/tribex/pen/mWNWdz

Comment: Thank you for your time and help sir.

Comment: The problem remained when I add more contents to the section. So I've gone through a jquery library and it's working now. Thank You.